# How do I upload my Maven project to GitHub?

Tags: java, eclipse, git, maven

I've looked around for the answer to this question, but I can't find any answers that I really understand. I would like to know how I can create a GitHub repository that stores only the necessary files from a Java Maven project that I've created in Eclipse.

Thanks!

Comment: Use this plugin, it will solve your problem. https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/ddlab-gitpusher

Comment: Make a lokal repository in git via `git init ` and add the appropriate files and commit later push that to the created repository on Github...